# Is there a way to extract the state of a flash object with javascript?

Tags: javascript, flash

I want to extract the actual visual state of a flash object and to get the contents of the current frame with javascript. Then I want to be able to reapply this state to a different Flash object on a separate page, so that the new Flash object looks exactly the same as the original. HTML5 canvas lets you do this easily, but can this be done with Flash? Note that I do not have control of the page that has the Flash content, but my Javascript will be included on the page.

Comment: If you don't control the page that has the flash element on it, then you won't be able to access anything.

Comment: @jbabey Please explain in more detail.

Comment: By the way you can have access to the markup of flash control and can easily access it through jQuery lik $("embed")

Comment: @gaurav Not just the HTML structure. I want the visual data.

Comment: @JustinMeltzer the flash element is part of the DOM of the page you don't control. attempting to access anything on that DOM will result in an `Access Denied` exception due to cross site scripting.

Comment: @jbabey My javascript will be on the page.

Comment: By visual data, do you mean the video content? Then you can check for the location which it is accessing. Use some fiddler or firebug kind of tools for that.

Comment: @gaurav Yes, I mean the actual video content. And I want to be able to access the current frame of the video being displayed at that time.

Comment: Nope, there's no way. You know Flash files are written in ActionScript and then are compiled. There's nothing like a state, it has its own logic. If there's an API for your special case, then maybe. But you have to be more specific then

Comment: @gaurav Similar to the type of functionality that html5 canvas' toDataUrl method would provide: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/html5-canvas/todataurl.html

Comment: @DanLee There's nothing like HTML5 Canvas's toDataUrl function for flash?

Comment: See that is the problem, HTML5 Canvas has it by default, while flash framework gives you the advantage to implement such functionality on your own. I don't think you can achieve this without modifying the flash object itself.

Comment: @gaurav Ok and so you mean that the ActionScript files would need to be modified?

Comment: Yeah that's right, you need some logic to be implemented in the action script itself so that it continuously gives callback to some js/flash method. Also check for the answer provided by @lostPixels

Comment: btw I got one more link which will help you achive this: http://blog.leeburrows.com/2011/10/p2p-flash-on-a-local-network-part1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you out, assuming you control the flash [JS screenshot flash movie](http://danielmclaren.com/2008/03/use-javascript-to-take-a-screenshot-of-a-flash-movie)

Comment: Awesome @Faisal Abid.. didn't think you are here :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the Flash, you can do some JS-to-AS3 communication with ExternalInterface to export the "state" of the Flash movie. You'll have to create a Flash function that stores all the variables that you'd like to replicate in other Flash movies.

Comment: Ok, so whoever controls the ActionScript files would need to create an ExternalInterface to give me access to the state of the movie?

Comment: Yup. They will need to send you the data that you wish to capture within the Flash movie.